# Linearization of a SDE and comparison to deterministic setting

Tags: stochastic-processes, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am a bit puzzled having no experience in this area on the following problem.

It is well know that if we consider a system as:

\begin{equation}
\dot x = f(x(t)), x \in R 
\end{equation}

with $f$ of class $C^{\infty}$ it possible to linearize the dynamic around the equlibria (and to be honest along a trajectory with appropriate modifications) via the computation of the Jacobian:

\begin{equation}
\delta \dot x = \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}|_{x=x^*}, \quad \delta x = x-x^*
\end{equation}

But how can a similar reasoning apply in the following stochastic setting? Consider for example:

\begin{equation}
dX = f(X)dt + \sqrt{\beta \cdot X}dW, \quad x \in R,\beta \in R, dW \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,dt)\,.
\end{equation}

where $dW$ is a Wiener process.

I imagine that Jacobian remains the same for $f(X)$ part but how is the term $\sqrt{\beta \cdot X}$ handled?

Comment: You should write it a is standard as $dX=f(X)dt+dW$, where $dW\sim N(0,dt)$. This should clear up about half of the issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I have indeed rewritten it, but in you equation there appears to be no function (of $X$, ie. $\sqrt(dx)$) multiplying $dW$, so I've done the appropriate modifications.

Comment: What is $dx$ and why is it there? Is that is just the product $d·x$?

Comment: Pardon the ambiguity, I have reformulated the text accounting for the fact that by $dx$ I am referring to the constant scalar value $d$ times $x$, i.e. $d \cdot x$. I have cleared the ambiguity by calling $d$ $\beta$

Comment: It should still be a capital $X$ in the diffusion coefficient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my specific problem however it definitely does not suite a formal treatment.

Specifically, I was investigating how to deal with the afore mentioned nonlinear diffusion terms in order to compute a linear model to be used by a [Kalman filter](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_di_Kalman).

It appears that it is a common practice - yet not mathematically formal - that the diffusion term is evaluated at the mean value or equilibria under considerations. See [this book](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/pub/sde_book.pdf)- *Applied Stochastic Differential Equations Simo Särkkä and Arno Solin* -, algorithm 9.4 p. 173.

This approximation results in having once again the Jacobian for the drift term $f(X)$ but the a diffusion term that varies with the equilibria/trajectory of the mean under consideration.